# How do I properly fill out the Georgia birth certificate request form?

Tags: birth-certificate, usa

Bit of a dumb question. I need to request a couple of copies of a Georgia birth certificate to use as proof of US citizenship but the top of the form is confusing me: https://dph.georgia.gov/sites/dph.georgia.gov/files/Birth-Certificate-Request-Form.pdf

What should I put in all of the boxes if I want 2 copies? Something like this?

```
[ 2 ] full size copies [ 2 ] total number of copies [ 2 ] amount received
                                                          $30
```

Or are some of these supposed to be checkboxes? I figure the `Photocopy of valid ID` field is just to remind me to include one?

Comment: I would think that 2 would go in the boxes as you've shown for the copies, and then perhaps a ✓ check mark in amount received and for the id.

Comment: @Dorothy That does make sense. I guess they'll understand what I need from the amount on the money order even if I get it wrong. Thank you.

Comment: I know it doesn't. I'm in Atlanta, where a lot of things don't make sense (and not from here ty).